# How to preview the thumbnail of any file

Tags: angularjs

I have number of files like .doc,.pptx, .avi.. that means i have uploaded number of files to my database using the angularjs and node api, now my query is,

How to show those uploaded file preview as thumbnail.

Comment: If you have extension, then it's pretty easy, no?

Comment: May be@dfsq, but i don't the actual procedure how to make it possible. If you know please let me know. It will be a great help

Comment: Your question is too broad to show anything concrete. Post your code maybe. Otherwise I can only give you general recommendations, like get file extension, then map extension to icon.

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problem are you running into?